# Bitcoin Payment Gateway in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, bitcoin

I want to integrate Bitcoin payment gateway in PHP
I have created Account here -> https://gourl.io/info/memberarea/My_Account.html
and I used this github API -> https://github.com/cryptoapi/Payment-Gateway

This request sent by my script -> 
https://coins.gourl.io/result.php?b/17104/p/17104AAs3ew6Bitcoin77BTCPUBpwgOMgxMq81Fn9nMCnWTGrm/u/99346995__7958333d57/o/invoice000383/e/UW1gcHtnY20%3D/l/en/i/AAwHFAx4e2h7eXx8bGs%3D/h/948f4a7a4972e9cf4a8d2fe730922fad/z/654116&_=1509347729277

I Got this response

```
{"status":"payment_not_received","err":"","public_key":"17104AAs3ew6Bitcoin77BTCPUBpwgOMgxMq81Fn9nMCnWTGrm"
,"box":17104,"boxtype":"captchabox","order":"invoice000383","user":"99346995__7958333d57","userformat"
:"","usercountry":"","period":"","amount":0,"amountusd":0,"coinlabel":"","coinname":"","addr":"","tx"
:"","confirmed":0,"timestamp":"","date":"","datetime":""}
```

Comment: I'm no expert on Bit-Coin, but `17104AAs3ew6Bitcoin77BTCPUBpwgOMgxMq81Fn9nMCnWTGrm` doesn't look like a valid public key to me!

Comment: I prefer https://payb.tc this is getting small percentage only. No additional fees.

Answer (score 0):

> 17104AAs3ew6Bitcoin77BTCPUBpwgOMgxMq81Fn9nMCnWTGrm

This gourl.io gateway key, not bitcoin key.

Here php example (bitcoin json) - https://github.com/cryptoapi/Payment-Gateway/blob/master/Examples/json.php